# Modulus Cancellation Law

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand the proof for cancellation law in modulus which states that:

```
    ak = bk mod m

<=>     m | (a-b)k
                    since (k,m) = 1
<=>     m | (a-b)

<=>     a = b mod m
```

However, I don't understand why:

> if $\,\gcd(k,m) = 1,\;$ then $\,m\mid(a-b)k \;\iff\; m\mid(a-b)$$

Can anybody help me please? :)

Comment: @BabakS. Not true. For instance let $a=4$, $b=2=c$.

Comment: No, @Babak, that only works when $a$ is prime.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: My mind was just confused. I am working on some other material. So sorry. :(

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use prime factorization. Since $m$ and $k$ have no prime in common and $m|(a-b)k$ then all primes in $m$ must appear in $a-b$.

Comment: Hm, I'm still not sure I get what you mean Vicinius...

Comment: In general, $l|s$ implies that there existes $t$ such that $lt=s$. The prime factorization of both sides must be equal. Let $p$ be a prime dividing $m$, and look at $tm = (a-b)k$, then $p$ must appear in the factorization of $(a-b)$ or $k$, but $(k,m) = 1$ implies that no prime can divide both $m$ and $k$, therefore $p$ must appear in the factoization of $(a-b)$. When you do this with all the primes in $m$, you'll see that $m$ itself is a factor of $(a-b)$, therefore $m|(a-b)$.

Comment: Aah oks thanks, got it now :)

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was stuck in my study of the old 997* (mod 1000000) random number generator.  For more info, see Knuth vol. 2 material on random number generators.  What we have here is an example of Polya's divide and conquer strategy, examining (a-b) and k separately.